# Is an 80-minute stopover enough time to clear Immigration at the Munich Airport?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, layovers, short-connections, muc

I am traveling from the US (Denver) to Vienna via Munich. I will be checking bags.  My stopover in Munich is a little over an hour, and I am concerned if this is enough time? Will my bags be checked all the way thru to Vienna or do I need to collect them in Munich and recheck them?

Can I make the connection in 80 minutes?

Comment: Which airline(s)? Do you have a through ticket, or have you booked the flights separately?

Comment: You should be OK, just tell the flight attendant before landing in Munich that you have a tight schedule; they sometime will make you leave the plane before other passengers, and they will also tell you, if they can which gate is your other plane.

Answer (score 2):

Cusatoms and immigration in EU/Schengen are seperate.

Immigration is handled at your point of entry to the Schengen area. In your case that is munich. Customs on the other hand is normally handled at your final airport, so you won't have to collect and re-check your baggage.

If the airline is prepared to sell you the flights on one ticket that means the airline thinks you will most likely make the connection. If you buy the flights on one ticket and are delayed on your incoming flight or held up in immigration then it's the airlines job to sort you out a replacement connection.

OTOH if you buy the flights on seperate tickets and you get delayed you are going to have to fork out for a new flight.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the trip on one ticket:

If the airline sold you such a ticket, there is enough time - otherwise they wouldn't sell it.
Anyway, an hour is easy to do in Munich. Worst case, if you miss your connection, you get a free rebooking on the next plane - and there are many to Vienna.

Your bags are checked through; german customs doesn't care about them.

Outside of the USA, basically all airports are 'international', so only the final arrival needs customs to inspect your bags. Only in the USA exists the concept of 'non-international' airports, so you are forced to immigrate and pass customs on the first ('international') arrival - your connection could be to Cornfield, IO, which might not have customs and immigration.

Comment: I think the last paragraph is stretching it rather too far. The EU has a particular one-of-a-kind system whereby the baggage of arriving international passengers is (usually) customs processed only at the final destination even after one or more EU-internal flights. But I don't think there are any other customs areas that have that kind of systems (including, for example, special marks on the bag tags of domestic travelers to make it clear _which_ bags have to be checked for travelers arriving on an internal flight).

Comment: The last paragraph is conflating two things: (1) sterile international transit, which the US does NOT have, but nearly all other countries do, and (2) the requirement to clear immigration at the first point of entry to the US, which is found elsewhere -- Canada, the UK and the Schengen zone at least all require you to clear immigration at the first stop within the respective states if you are proceeding to a "domestic" flight. Customs varies, but even Canada requires you to clear customs at your first Canadian point of entry as well.